# Access a resource from a depending project

Tags: java, spring, getresource, resource-loading

```
ProjectA
    -src/main/java
        -com.myApp.accessor
            -resourceAccessor.java
    -src/test/resources
        -context.xml
    -target/test-classes/context.xml

ProjectB (dependent on ProjectA)
    -src/main/java
        -xyz.java
```

Now I need to access the context.xml from ProjectB. What I'm doing is:

```
Class resourceAccessor{

    public static void loadFile(){
       ....
       this.getClass().getResources("/context.xml").getPath;
       ....
    }
}
```

in xyz, I have

```
resourceAccessor.loadFile();
```

But this throws null pointer exception.

Comment: Can you tell us how you build your application and what is on the classpath when you run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by putting the context.xml into src/main/resources/com.myApp.accessor/context.xml. Then use

```
getClass().getResource("context.xml").getPath()
```